# Total Probability Explanation Required for a Specific Case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have solved the problem using definitions but I am not able to convince myself on one thing. Kindly if someone can throw some light to simplify the matter. Explanation required for the step between.

**Problem**

Given that $Y \sim \text{Uni}[0,4]$, $W \sim \text{Uni}[0,8]$ and $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda(y)=\frac{1}{5-y}$.

Find

i) $\mathbb{P}(W<Y)$, and

ii) $\mathbb{P}(W>X+Y)$.

**Solution**

i)

$$\mathbb{P}(W<Y)= \int\limits_0^4 \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_0^y \frac{1}{8} \,dw \,dx=\frac{1}{4}$$

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have added the picture of the region.

ii)

$$\mathbb{P}(W>X+Y)= \int\limits_0^4 \mathbb{P}(W>X+Y\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\,dy $$ using total probability theorem

$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y)=\frac{1}{5-y}e^{-\frac{x}{5-y}},\quad x\geq0$

$F_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y)=1-e^{-\frac{x}{5-y}},\quad x\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise

$$\mathbb{P}(W>X+Y)= \int\limits_0^4 \mathbb{P}(X<W-Y\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\,dy $$

---

$$\mathbb{P}(W>X+Y)=\int\limits_0^4 \int\limits_y^8 F_{X\mid Y}(w-y)f_W(w)f_Y(y)\,dw\,dy$$

I have used the fact

$$f_{S-U}(z)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_S(s)f_U(s-z)\,ds$$

---

Need explanation for the above step, If possible some easy explanation with diagram. I assume the fact of fixing the value of $Y=y$ and then solving convolution of $W-X$, subtraction of the random variables.

$$\int\limits_0^4 \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_0^y \frac{1}{8} \int\limits_0^{w-y} \underbrace{\frac{1}{5-y}e^{-\frac{x}{5-y}}}_{f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y)} \,dx \,dw \,dy$$

$$\frac{12}{32} + \frac{1}{32} \int\limits_0^4 (5-y)e^{-\frac{8-y}{5-y}}\,dy $$

$$\frac{12}{32} + \frac{1.7584}{32}$$

Comment: Used for W and X they are independent

Comment: When we select $Y=y$ then $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is a function of $X$ and $W$ and $X$ are independent so use the definition of $W-X$ as subtraction of two independent random variables. The answer is correct. If someone has graphical description or solve it with some other way which is more easily comprehend able. Regards

Comment: Reading it right now. The first line of your solution is correct, but the diagram is wrong. Clearly, the line of w=y should have slope 1, not 2.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin Wang, I have corrected the figure. Learning pgfplots these days.